# A coin-tossing game with an unexpected expected value?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider independent tosses of a rather biased coin that has $$\begin{align}
\Pr({\tt Head})&=1/G\\
\Pr({\tt Tail})&=1-\Pr({\tt Head}),\end{align}$$ 
where $G$ is [Graham's Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number). Let the first $100$ tosses establish a "target" pattern, then let $N$ be the number of *additional* tosses needed to get a repetition of that target pattern (allowing overlap). E.g., a sequence that begins with $101$ consecutive ${\tt Tail}$s would have $N=1$.

**Question**: $\ \mathbb{E}(N)\ =\ ?\quad$

I'm posting in the spirit of [this advice](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), and will eventually post the answer if no one else does so.

Comment: I like your title

Comment: My intuition is as follows. Obviously, it is very likely that you will flip 100 tails, and then flip another tail, making $N=1$. Yet, if you flip heads, you need a ton of trials before you repeat that feat of luck, making $N$ really large. This has a pretty low chance though. Thus it seems that the probability distribution does not matter.

The amount of tosses ($100$) plays a role, however. My bet is that $\mathbb{E}(N) $ is linear wrt to the number of tosses, something like $100e$.

Comment: Aha.  The $G$ number is a red herring. The answer is $2^{100}$. Using renewal theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ denote the set of all $2^{100}$ binary strings. Let $S$ be the random initial string of size 100. Then
$$E[N] = \sum_{s \in A} E[N|S=s]P[S=s] $$
Now observe that $P[S=s]>0$ for all $s \in A$.  So fix $s =(s_1, ..., s_{100})\in A$.  We compute $E[N|S=s]$.  Consider this thought experiment of random flipping:  Deterministically fix the first 100 flips as the string $s$.  Then randomly flip forever after (i.e., after time 100). Let $\{X_1, X_2, X_3, …\}$ represent the i.i.d. sequence of inter-arrival times of the string $s$ (including overlaps).  Then 
$$E[N|S=s] = E[X_1]$$ 
Let $M_t$ be the total number of occurrences of the string up to time $t \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ (including overlaps). By renewal theory we know
$$ \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{E[M_t]}{t}  = \frac{1}{E[X_1]} $$
On the other hand we can write $M_t$ via indicator functions: 
$$ M_t = \sum_{i=1}^t 1_i$$
where $1_i$ is an indicator function that is 1 if an occurence of string $s$ ends in location $i$, and 0 else. Then
$$ E[M_t] = \sum_{i=1}^t P[1_i=1] $$
and we note that for all $i \geq 200$ we have 
$$P[1_i=1]=P[\mbox{Flip $i$ is $s_{100}$, Flip $i-1$ is $s_{99}$, ..., Flip $i-99$ is $s_1$}] = P[S=s]$$ 
So 
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{E[M_t]}{t} = P[S=s] $$
Thus, $E[X_1] =\frac{1}{P[S=s]}$. Hence: 
$$ E[N] = \sum_{s \in A} \frac{1}{P[S=s]} P[S=s] = |A| = 2^{100}$$

Comment: The answer $2^{100}$ is the same for any value of $P[Head] \in (0,1)$, including $P[Head] = 1/G$. This is because in all such situations we have $P[S=s]>0$ for all $s \in A$. On the other hand, if $P[Head]=1$ or $P[Head]=0$ then obviously $N=1$ with probability 1, and so $E[N]=1$.

Comment: (+1) Nice answer. The attention-getter for me is that the result is *independent of the probabilities* (assuming only that they are nonzero). This is also a special case of a very general theorem with a very short proof [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1426993).